# Is it possible to include svg tag in the image url in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a complex svg but as an example Consider that I have the below svg

```
<svg id="circle-svg" width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
```

To include it in an img tag i need to save it as a separate file say
circle.svg and then include it in img as

```
<img src="circle.svg" />
```

Question:
Say i dont want to have a separate file, is it possible to include it in the image based on an id or so?

```
<img src="#circle-svg" />
```

Additional context:

One of the main reason being, I should be able to resize the svg based on its container say width: 100% or height:100%, the content of svg uses absolute paths and hence i cannot have svg dimension itself in percentage so thought of including it in image tag

Comment: Images in HTML are already vector scalable , but HTML height and width should be kept the same size as the image, so the don't scale (takes time). If you want them to scale though, you can already do that with JavaScript or CSS.

Comment: Yes you can use a [dataURI version](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs). But then all external resources won't load, and all CSS styles, not inlined will be lost. To create one from a DOM element you can do `var svgData = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg); var url ='data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, ' + encodeURIComponent(svgData);`

Comment: The additional context make no sense. You should describe that problem with an example of what you've written and describe exactly why it doesn't work. It seems that your SVG needs a viewBox but it's hard to be sure without you providing additional details.